# What is the difference between Fine-Tuning and Resuming of training in Caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have been training my network for 100,000 iterations. After that I wanted to continue the training. But there are basically two options to do that and I do not understand the difference between them:

First:

```
$SOLVER=...
$WEIGHTS=...
$LOGGGING=...

caffe train -solver $SOLVER -weights $WEIGHTS 2>&1 | tee $LOGGING
```

and second:

```
$SOLVER=...
$SNAPSHOT=...
$LOGGGING=...

caffe train -solver $SOLVER -snapshot $SNAPSHOT 2>&1 | tee $LOGGING
```

Is there a big difference between the first and second method? I have been using the first method which is called fine-tuning. But I did not really understand the difference between the first and second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine-Tuning : Usually done on different dataset model trained on. Training parameters might be different. Weights are saved without any solverstate.

Resuming : Possible reasons to use because program halted for some reason.
Snapshot includes weights and solverstate, Solverstate has information about training parameters such as LR, max_iter etc.,. When you resume (snapshot), solver restores the previous state and continuous training.

Both are same if training parameters are same. Usually, we change learning rate, momentum and max_iterations for fine-tuning.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, so if I do not change the `hyper parameters` fine-tuning is basically the same as resuming the network? But I could for example change the `max_iterations` parameter which would make it possible for me to "expand" my training?

Comment: Yes, both are same if hyper_params are not changed. I am not sure about the 2nd question - I don't think when you resume, you can change any params including max_iterations. Have to verify it though.

Comment: No no, I meant when I do fine-tuning with `-weights $WEIGHTS´ then I can easily increase `max_iterations`.

Comment: Yeah.. you can do that !